# Unable to see the option targated runtime in Eclipse project properties for integration of project with tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, eclipse-plugin, spring-integration

Eclipse project-> properties-> targated runtime(missing)
Unable to see the option targated runtime in Eclipse project properties for integration of  project with tomcat

Comment: have you added a tomcat server to your project ??

Answer (score 0):

1) First Add the server to your project in Eclipse.
2) Right-click on the project to properties will get even if you not getting **targeted runtime** update eclipse.

refer to the below Screenshot.[image]